# XML Parsing Error : no element found

Tags: xml, xss

Actually I was testing a website for XSS and when I injected a couple of custom payloads +alert("XSS") & aLeRT(String.fromCharCode(75,67,70)) into the url it throws a XML Parsing Error: no element found. What does this actually mean? And this happens only in Firefox other browsers don't throw any error. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Provide relevant code that you're using.

Comment: I use these 2 payloads **<SCRIPT>+alert("XSS")</SCRIPT>** & **<ScRIPt<aLeRT(String.fromCharCode(75,67,70))</ScRIPt>**

Comment: [Edit] it in the question.